# Why doesn't Python return an error for string assignment using replace in a for loop?

Tags: python

In the following example, I would have expected an error saying that string assignment is not possible because strings are immutable. Instead, the loop returns the original string.

```
a = "AECD"

for i in a:
    if i == "E":
        a.replace(i, "B")
        print(a)
```

Is replace not essentially trying to do the same thing as a[1] = "B"? Does this have to do with creating a new object with assignment versus modifying an existing one with replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.replace(i, "B")
```

does not change the original string `a`. Instead, it returns the string which results from replacing `i` in `a`. 
In your loop, you are merely evaluating an expression and dropping it on the floor.

You could do it this way:

```
a = "AECD"

for i in a:
    if i == "E":
        a = a.replace(i, "B")
        print(a)
```

In this version, you take the string with the replacement, and you assign that value to the variable `a`, which gives you the effect you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = "AECD"

for i in a:
    if i == "E":
        b = a.replace(i, "B")
        print (b)
        print(a)
```

Comment: "Try this" with a code dump is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not doing a string assignment, this is not an error. A new string is being created and is returned by the `str.replace()` method. You are throwing it away by not assigning it to anything, however.